# Как сделать асинхронный счетчик/триггер на время?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, дата

Пишу телеграм бота на aiogram. Ботом будет пользоваться большое кол-во людей и в боте есть модуль заказа.

Задача этого модуля - создание заказов, которые должны закрываться в какие-то указанные сроки.

Допустим бот запрашивает дату и время закрытия заказа, пользователь вводит дату: 2022-08-17 и время: 19:00. И наш заказ должен будет закрыться 2022-08-17 числа в 19:00.

Опять же, нужно не забывать, что таких заказов будет много и мне нужен какой-то оптимизированный и асинхронный вариант для этой задачи, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как костыльный вариант предлагаю это.
Его проблема в том что если бот перезапустится все отсчеты исчезнут.
По красивому, стоит сделать отдельную таску которая каждую минуту или час проверяет из бд все заказы, которые у вас в `data['datetime']`(и которые нужно туда занести).

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class InputDateTime(StatesGroup):
    input_date = State()
    input_time = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите дату в формате 'ДД-ММ-ГГГГ'")
    await InputDateTime.input_date.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=InputDateTime.input_date)
async def input_date(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    res = message.text.split("-")
    if len(res) == 3 and all(map(lambda date: date.isdigit(), res)):
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            if len(res[2]) == 4:
                data['date'] = res
                await message.answer("Введите время в формате 'ЧЧ-ММ'")
                await InputDateTime.next()
                return

    await message.answer("Неверный формат даты")


@dp.message_handler(state=InputDateTime.input_time)
async def input_time(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    res = message.text.split("-")
    if len(res) == 2 and all(map(lambda date: date.isdigit(), res)):
        hour, minute = res

        async with state.proxy() as data:
            day, month, year = data['date']
            day, month, hour, minute = map(lambda number: f"{int(number):02}", (day, month, hour, minute))
            del data['date']
            data['datetime'] = datetime.strptime(f"{day}/{month}/{year} {hour}:{minute}", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
            if data['datetime'] > datetime.now():
                print("заказ принят")
                
                await asyncio.sleep(timedelta.total_seconds(data['datetime'] - datetime.now()))
                await message.answer("Время пришло")

    else:
        await message.answer("Неверный формат даты")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Есть библиотека apscheduler и она вроде позволяет работать с триггерами, но я не знаю на сколько она пригодная в моем примере

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/

Comment: просто как я понял в вашем примере, весь код будет на паузе пока не выполнится закрытие заказа. Все, что ниже `await asyncio.sleep(timedelta.total_seconds(data['datetime'] - datetime.now()))` - не выполнится

Comment: Нет, не будет. Это асинхронный слип.

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Вроде получилось, все же использовал ваш способ, он более официальный, как по мне. У меня также есть вопрос, если я сделал сброс состояния с сохранением данных, то в дальнейшем при запуске других состояний данные сбросятся или будут также доступны и существовать в других состояниях до тех пор, пока мы окончательно не пропишем finish?

Comment: Если state.reset_state(with_data=false) то данные останутся